# Questions about reusing toolbar across multiple activities

Tags: android

I'm new to Android developing, and probably this question has an easy answer that I'm unable to figure out.

I currently want to use a toolbar in almost every activity of my app. I've created a base activity with all the item listeners and a method that sets the toolbar `(setSupportActionBar)`, and the XML that only has the toolbar and its settings. This part alone works fine.

Now, my questions come when I want any activity to extend this base activity:

- Do I have to setContentView in both the base and the child activity?
- If I set the toolbar in the base activity in the onCreate method when I setContentView in the child activity after calling super.onCreate it gets overridden. The only thing that works now is calling super.onCreate in the child, then setContentView(childLayout), then calling an extended method of base activity that sets the toolbar. I feel like this is kinda hacky and there should be better ways to do it.
- Do I have to manually add the toolbar to the XML of each child activity? This isn't a big problem, but I feel like there may be a way to "automatically" add it to every child.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: easier way will be using styles.xml

Comment: Can you expand on this @VivekMishra?

Comment: First try expanding it yourself. Your app theme should extend from `ActionBar` theme

Answer (score 0):

- Do I have to setContentView in both the base and the child activity?

  -> No you don't have to setContentView in both. only set in child activity will be fine.
- If I set the toolbar in the base activity in the onCreate method,
  when I setContentView in the child activity after calling
  super.onCreate it gets overriden. The only thing that works now is
  calling super.onCreate in the child, then
  setContentView(childLayout), then calling an extended method of
  baseActivity that sets the toolbar. I feel like this is kinda hacky
  and there should be better ways to do it.

  -> Include toolbar layout in activity where you want to use. if you want to use in every activity then include in every xml.
- Do I have to manually add the toolbar to the xml of each child
  activity? This isn't a big problem, but I feel like there may be a
  way to "automatically" add it in every child.

  -> Yes initiate toolbar in **onCreate()** of every activity. i don't think there is another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your **BaseActivity** like this

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentView());

    // here you can do common things for all activities like toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); // Note: every activity xml should have toolbar.
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    onViewReady(savedInstanceState, getIntent());
}

protected void onViewReady(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
    // To be used by child activities.
}

protected abstract int getContentView();
}
```

And **extends BaseActivity** in child activity as

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity{
 @Override
protected int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.activity_child;
}

@Override
protected void onViewReady(Bundle savedInstanceState, Intent intent) {
    super.onViewReady(savedInstanceState, intent);
   // initializations....
}
}
```